# Group By and Sum Horizontally

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I am trying to do a Group By, based on quarter-end dates, and Sum all values below these quarter-end dates.  I did some Googling before posting here.  This is the line of code that I tried.

```
 grouped_and_summed = grouped_and_summed.groupby(axis=1, level=0).sum()
```

The data frame is named `grouped_and_summed` and the axis, I think is 1, and the level, I think is 0.  After I ran the code, I have the same grouped_and_summed.shape that I had before I ran the code.  Here is a screen shot of my data, exported to a CSV file.  I merged several columns together to show 2001Q1 repeating, 2001Q2 repeating, etc.  I want to group by these quarter-end dates and sum everything (horizontally) under this row.

[image]

This: `grouped_and_summed.head()`

Gives me this:

```
           0       1       2       3       4       5      ...   14481   14482  \
index     2001Q1  2001Q2  2001Q3  2001Q4  2002Q1  2002Q2  ...  2011Q2  2011Q3   
RCFD3531       0       1       2       3       4       5  ...   14481   14482   
RCFD3532       0       0       0       0       0       0  ...       0       0   
RCFD3533       0       0       0       0       0       0  ...       0       0   
RCFD3534       0       0       0       0       0       0  ...       0       0   

           14483   14484   14485   14486  
index     2011Q4  2012Q1  2012Q2  2012Q3  
RCFD3531   14483   14484   14485   14486  
RCFD3532       0       0       0       0  
RCFD3533       0       0       0       0  
RCFD3534       0       0       0       0  

[5 rows x 14487 columns]
```

Somehow, I'd like to get rid of that very top row too.  The one above the 'index'.

Answer (score 0):

If you read your csv using

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

try add `skiprows`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to do a group by (the row named index) and sum (all values below the quarter-end dates).

Comment: Notice your output of `head()` says 5 rows, the row of strings `2001Q1`, `2001Q2`, etc is one of the rows of your dataframe, instead of column names. I believe you want that to be column names so you can do the sum.

Comment: I re-named the index to Quarter_End, and ran this code:

d = {'index':'Quarter_End'}
grouped_and_summed = grouped_and_summed.rename(columns=d).groupby('Quarter_End', sort=False, as_index=False)["Total Amount"].sum()

That didn't work for me.  The error that I got was: KeyError: 'Quarter_End'

Comment: I think that's obvious. You don't have a column named "index" so you cannot rename it. Try run `print(grouped_and_summed.dtypes)` you will see what columns you have there.

Comment: I did that. Finally got it working. Thanks!